# How to add scrollbar to groupbox? C# 4.0

Tags: c#, scrollbar

So... did someone know how to make it?...

In a panel is easy, because we can set the "AutoScroll" property, to true... but groupbox doesn't have it.

Anyways... exists some way for it?, thanks in advance ;-).

Comment: Interesting... I've never seen one, interested to see where this goes. I don't know of a way to do this.

Comment: Group boxes don't have scroll bars. They would look quite revolting if they did.

Comment: @David Yes i know, but... i'm making this for some reason, i know the esthetic risks.

Comment: @ Daas Cook: Please draw us a picture of what you want. It might be that there's a better solution to your larger problem.

Comment: @ Daas Cook: You should be polite towards, who are trying to solve your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A vertically-scrollable GroupBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914141/a-vertically-scrollable-groupbox)

Answer (score 60):

Quite simple... Add a panel inside a group box.

Comment: @Daas Do you expect us to read your mind? I can't see anywhere in your question a screenshot illustrating what you are looking for.

Comment: @Daas Cook your question is vague, so you got a vague answer.  It's the same answer I would have given.

Comment: Yes, i know... i also know that: "the quality of answer is proportional to the quality of question". Ok guys, excuse me but i cannot write in english so nice... perhaps in another oportunity will i explain better.

Comment: @Daas Give us a screenshot of what you want. At present we can't tell.

Comment: @Daas - yes, pictures don't require translation for the most part.

Comment: You would have to add two panels

Answer (score 3):

Declare Group box object and Panel object which will contain the scroll bar by default and some of my Check box objects;I read somewhere that Group box's don't have scroll bar for aesthetic reasons(i hope it's not true, why not let the user make that call).  Solution is simple, once you know that you will create a panel that will lay on top of your group box just to get your scroll bar.

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox grpDR;//GROUPBOX IN WHICH PANEL WILL OVERLAY
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel grpScrlDR;//PANEL WHICH WILL HAVE SCROLL BAR AND CONTAIN CHECK BOXES

private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox chkDr2;
private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox chkDr1;

 private void InitializeComponent()
{
  this.grpScrlDR = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
  this.chkDr2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
  this.chkDr1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
  this.grpDR = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();

  this.grpScrlDR.SuspendLayout();
  this.grpDR.SuspendLayout();


// 
// grpScrlDR
// PANEL DETAILS ADDING CHECKBOX CONTROLS AND ENABLING AUTO SCROLL
  this.grpScrlDR.AutoScroll = true;
  this.grpScrlDR.Controls.Add(this.chkDr2);
  this.grpScrlDR.Controls.Add(this.chkDr1);
  this.grpScrlDR.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.grpScrlDR.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 336);
  this.grpScrlDR.Name = "grpScrlDR";
  this.grpScrlDR.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(175, 230);
  this.grpScrlDR.TabIndex = 0;

// 
// chkDr2
// 
  this.chkDr2.AutoSize = true;`
  this.chkDr2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 45);
  this.chkDr2.Name = "chkDr2";
  this.chkDr2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(54, 20);
  this.chkDr2.TabIndex = 1;
  this.chkDr2.Text = "Permit#";
  this.chkDr2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  this.chkDr2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.chkDr_CheckedChanged);

// 
// chkDr1
// 
  this.chkDr1.AutoSize = true;
  this.chkDr1.Checked = true;
  this.chkDr1.CheckState = System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked;
  this.chkDr1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 22);
  this.chkDr1.Name = "chkDr1";
  this.chkDr1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(54, 20);
  this.chkDr1.TabIndex = 0;
  this.chkDr1.Text = "Account";
  this.chkDr1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  this.chkDr1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.chkDr_CheckedChanged);

// 
// grpDR
// GROUP BOX DETAILS - GROUP BOX IS ADDING PANEL CONTROLS
  this.grpDR.Controls.Add(this.grpScrlDR);
  this.grpDR.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

  this.grpDR.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 336);
  this.grpDR.Name = "grpDR";
  this.grpDR.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(175, 230);
  this.grpDR.TabIndex = 46;
  this.grpDR.TabStop = false;
  this.grpDR.Text = "Report by";
  this.grpDR.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GroupBox` cannot display a scroll bar. If you need a control similar to a `GroupBox` that can contain a scroll bar, see the `Panel` control

[Read This Article - Find (The GroupBox cannot display a scroll bar) Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a panel inside of your GroupBox, Dock a Panel inside of the GroupBox and set the AutoScroll property on the docked Panel to true. You can then place any controls you need inside of the GroupBox on the Panel, which will scroll when necessary.

If you don't like the way that looks as you stated above, then you have two possible options:

1. There may be a way to hack (more like "abuse" in this situation) the GroupBox control by making calls into the native Win32 API to add a scrollbar. I rarely use native calls on managed controls, but I've done this in situations where, for instance, I need to disable the scroll bar on a ListView as ListView doesn't expose this property. Below I expose the native Win32 function for use in C#, just call SetScrollBarVisible to enable or disable the scrollbar as needed from your code (I have not tested this on a GroupBox):
2. If aesthetics is THAT important to you (not a bad thing, user experience is greatly underappreciated in many areas of the application development world) and adding a scroll bar to the GroupBox doesn't work/look good to you, you will need to find another solution. I would imagine the best solution would be to make your own control from the ground up that meets your expectations (or modify the scrollbar itself, no idea how to do this), though this is can be a lot more work than it might be worth.

Here is how I expose and call the Win32 function SetScrollBar from my C# code (sorry, the DllImport won't format as a code block for some reason):

[DllImport ("user32")]
    private static extern long ShowScrollBar (long hwnd , long wBar, long bShow);

```
long SB_HORZ = 0;
long SB_VERT = 1;
long SB_BOTH = 3;

private static void SetScrollBarVisible (Control control, long sb, bool enable)
{
    if (control != null) return;
    if (enable)
        ShowScrollBar(control.Handle.ToInt64(), sb, 1);
    else
        ShowScrollBar(control.Handle.ToInt64(), sb, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would have to add 1 panel to the groupbox and set the autoscroll property to true.

Then you would add a second panel which would be large then the first panel.
On this second panel (StringPanel in the beleow code) you would add controls.

```
System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox StringsGroup;
System.Windows.Forms.Panel StingPanel;
System.Windows.Forms.Panel StringPanel2;

StringsGroup = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
StingPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
StringPanel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();

//Add your controls to StringPanel
StingPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 800);

StringPanel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(325, 345);
StringPanel2.AutoScroll = true;

this.StringPanel2.Controls.Add(StingPanel);
this.StringsGroup.Controls.Add(this.StringPanel2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Horizontal Scroll Bar Tip**

If you have a panel where all the controls contained within it are anchored to the top (so that they are centered) you will never see the horizontal scroll bar.  You need to have at least one control that is anchored left & top that disappears when the panel is too small to show it in order for the horizontal scroll bar to appear.  I put a label with hidden text on the panel to accomplish this.

This little tidbit took me quite a while to discover!  Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want scrollbars, but want your GroupBox to grow, you can edit these below properties from the Layout section as shown below.

```
AutoSize = true;

AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly;
```