# A vertically-scrollable GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am creating an application using *Windows Application Forms*. I'm basically new to C# and Visual Studio(Been using it since yesterday). So far, I've succeeded in creating a simplistic form as shown in the screenshot.

## My Form

[image: My Form Application]

## Background/Details

I am fetching data from a MySQL table using the IP provided in the box. This data is being loaded into a `DataSet`. Since last 10 hours, I've played around with displaying them into each one of these:

- DataGridView
- TableLayoutPanel

Putting them in the remaining part of the form windows. But both the outputs were not what I wanted them to be. One of the columns I am fetching is a `VARCHAR` ranging up to `190 chars`. The final results in both the cases was not quite easy to read, which brings me to my question.

## Question

So, now I am thinking of showing the text inside a **`GroupBox`**, with a vertical scroll-bar. The data from the `DataSet` can be displayed inside a `Label` or `LinkLabel` depending on the requirements.

Is this method feasible(time-optimization)? Is there some other kind of box/view which can satisfy my conditions? I'll be fetching and displaying **at-most 225 rows** from main table and *at least 2 links* for each of them fetched from another table(inside the `foreach` loop).

Please suggest me any other optimal solution for this job. Also, how can I add 200+ labels to a `GroupBox` and make the box vertically scrollable. As far as I can see in **Visual Studio 2010**, anything like `VerticalScroll` property doesn't exist for `GroupBox`.

Comment: A GroupBox should have an `AutoScroll` property. But you should think about the 200+ labels again. That's not a good thing.

Comment: Unless you are required to use winforms, WPF might be a better option.  WPF has a container called Stackpanel that can be placed inside a Scrollviewer object that will do exactly what you want.  Your individual objects would be added to the Stackpanel.

Comment: If you expand upon "The final results in both the cases was not quite easy to read, which brings me to my question." you'll get a much better result via assistance with DataGridView. A groupbox - no way.

Comment: @Joey I can notice a `AutoSize` property associated to the Box. But it doesn't allow scroll, it just extends the box beyond the window.

Comment: @rism The output I was getting was A. Not looking much pretty/user-friendly. B. I couldn't find anything to have my links in there too.

Comment: @nCdy I'm using the toolbox and can not see any object named `Grid`. :( Perhaps it is from another type of Application Projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a panel to Groupbox it has the Scrollable property or you can achieve it through RichTextBox

Comment: As I mentioned[*new to C# and Visual Studio; using it since **yesterday***) mentioning the recognizable names would be of much help. Also, a quick guide on how to append data to them.

Comment: There is another control which has the Scroll property System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()

Answer (score 4):

Put everything inside an auto-sizing groupBox (`AutoSize = True`) and throw that groupBox inside a panel with the auto-scroll set (`AutoScroll = True`).